# Why are unicoin questions being closed by moderator and not by the community?

Tags: discussion, unicoins

There is a new feature, perhaps tongue in cheek, introduced to Stack Overflow, and people are asking questions about it.  The questions are valid discussions asking about the new features.

Most of these questions are being closed unilaterally by moderators, and for reasons that are not valid.

If there is a valid need for these questions to be closed, could a new "hold reason" be added that addresses the exact reason why they are being closed, since none of the current reasons suit?

Otherwise, would the moderators please consider allowing the community to vote to choose when enough is enough, and decide which questions are "good enough" to stick around during this holiday via normal voting methods?

Comment: I guess I saw that coming.  This is what happens when SE doesn't send you that memo about the TPS reports.

Comment: Probably because they don't want to spoil the, er, surprise

Comment: Because people who are in timezones where it's not yet 1st April are butthurt

Comment: New custom close reason: "Because Unicorns."

Comment: Egads. Does SE Inc. already regret this?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'd buy that.

Comment: To be fair, though, some of these questions are just fabricated crap that I don't see why we need on Meta. I realize this is April Fool's Day, but seriously, there *are* still real issues that occur on this day and we don't need pages of our main meta site flooded with useless nonsense about unicoins, drowning out important problems users might be having.

Comment: @animuson, tl;not enough unicorns

Comment: @RobertHarvey Excellent idea. [Added](http://i.stack.imgur.com/EXeyg.png).

Answer (score 29):

Refer all complaints to Anna Lear at the Stack Exchange Corporate Office.  You're welcome.

Comment: ಠ_ಠ `(╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻)`

Answer (score 13):

Because said moderator feels angry and bitter about not being able to see them yet. And so had ensued in a murderous unicidal journey to burn off anything related to unicorn.

## Robert Harvey! The Unicorn Hater!

Comment: I am soooo bitter.  +1

Comment: Adding fuel to the hate fire!!

Comment: [Burn, baby, burn!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5jzMw9ezE3I)